# MongoDB cluster - CSRS failing to start

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, devops

I'm trying ti configure mongo sharded cluster with docker on local environment, following [this guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/) and got stuck on the first step. The problem is, that configuration server replica set could not start correctly.
[image]

I've tried [to disable](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/read-concern-majority/#disable-read-concern-majority) **enableMajorityReadConcern** but didn't succeed. It looks like config servers are obliged to have this set to true.
Those look strange for me:

```
*2018-11-14T16:55:38.669+0000 I REPL     [initandlisten] Did not find local replica set configuration document at startup; NoMatchingDocument: Did not find replica set configuration document in local.system.replset* 

*2018-11-14T16:55:38.669+0000 I CONTROL 
[LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Failed to create config.system.sessions:
Cannot create config.system.sessions until there are shards, will try
again at the next refresh interval* 

*2018-11-14T16:55:38.669+0000 I
CONTROL  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Sessions collection is not set
up; waiting until next sessions refresh interval: Cannot create
config.system.sessions until there are shards*
```

I've tried 3 container instances scenario - all 3 display the same log output as the single container scenario. Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue. When CSRS is up for the first time - it's an expected behavior. rs.init() command (step#3 from deployment guide) **must be executed via mongo shell** to make CSRS finally configured & up. Command could be executed on any single node of CSRS.